# How to config show labels stackedbar chart processbar 100% outside in top or bottom chart

Tags: javascript, charts, report

I want to show a report chart stacked bar 1 row same process bar 100%. I show labels of the item in the outside chart (bottom or top chart). Do you know a library that has a chart that can draw it? Please introduce to me it.
Thanks

[image: Image example]

Comment: Have you tried https://www.google.com/search?q=charts+javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm Image-Charts founder.

[Image-Charts](https://www.image-charts.com/) can help you with that:

```
<img src="https://image-charts.com/chart?cht=bhs&chs=700x100&chd=t:10|20|30&chco=4d89f9,c6d9fd,00B88A&chl=10%|20%|30%">
```

[image]

Comment: it's not working when i want to show value percent in Top or Bottom Chart .